# document.querySelector skip element that's not there

Tags: javascript, prebid.js

i'm adding adverts in to pages using this, i have about 5 ads on pages each into a different element.  the problem i'm getting is on some pages all the elements arn't there, so i want to "skip" them if they arn't there, a at the moment its finding the first element, adding an advert, if the next element isnt there on the page, it errors out and then wont show the adverts in the following elements which are there. hopefully this makes sense?

this element is on some page, but not others, so how can i "skip it" on pages where its not there

```
document.querySelector("#spacer1").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',........
```

Full code using:

```
//shows the slots on the page
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelector(".p-body-inner").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423"><div id="advertisement" style="border: 0pt none; margin: auto; text-align: center; color: #999; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .2em; line-height: 1; margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top: -4px;">Advertisement</div><div id="inreedvid13Slot"></div></div><br>');
  document.querySelector("#spacer1").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423"><div id="advertisement" style="border: 0pt none; margin: auto; text-align: center; color: #999; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .2em; line-height: 1; margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top: -4px;">Advertisement</div><div id="inreedvid9Slot"></div></div><br><br><br>');
  document.querySelector(".block.block--category.block--category99").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br><div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423"><div id="advertisement" style="border: 0pt none; margin: auto; text-align: center; color: #999; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .2em; line-height: 1; margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top: -4px;">Advertisement</div><div id="inreedvid8Slot"></div></div>');
  document.querySelector("#spacer2").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<br><div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423"><div id="advertisement" style="border: 0pt none; margin: auto; text-align: center; color: #999; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .2em; line-height: 1; margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top: -4px;">Advertisement</div><div id="inreedvid5Slot"></div></div><br>');
  document.querySelector(".p-breadcrumbs.p-breadcrumbs--bottom").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<br><div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423"><div id="advertisement" style="border: 0pt none; margin: auto; text-align: center; color: #999; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .2em; line-height: 1; margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top: -4px;">Advertisement</div><div id="inreedvid4Slot"></div></div><br>');
  document.querySelector("#adfooter").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<br><div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423"><div id="advertisement" style="border: 0pt none; margin: auto; text-align: center; color: #999; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .2em; line-height: 1; margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top: -4px;">Advertisement</div><div id="inreedvid6Slot"></div></div><br>');
});
```

so the above works now thanks to the answer below, much appreciated:
the next problem is it now gives errors because my prebid file is trying to place "slots" on the page where the div slot has been excluded/ skipped due to the helpful answer, so i think i need some logic, to stop the slots being sent to page when that slots div has been excluded?
 this is the code that is sending the slots from the prebid file:

```
(window.googletag, window.pbjs, {
definitons: {
inreedvid13Slot: { adUnitPath: "/slotnumber/slotname", size: [[970, 90],[970, 250],[728, 90],[468, 60],[320, 50],[320, 100]], sizeMapping: "mappingleaderslot", timeout: site_config.refresh_rate, },
inreedvid9Slot: { adUnitPath: "/slotnumber/slotname", size: [[300, 600],[300, 250],[250, 250],[160, 600],[120, 600]], sizeMapping: "mappingmenuslot", timeout: site_config.refresh_rate, },
inreedvid5Slot: { adUnitPath: "/slotnumber/slotname", size: [[300, 600],[300, 250],[250, 250],[160, 600],[120, 600]], sizeMapping: "mappingmenuslot", timeout: site_config.refresh_rate, },
inreedvid8Slot: { adUnitPath: "/slotnumber/slotname", size: [[550, 310],[728, 90],[300, 250],[250, 250],[468, 60],[320, 50],[336, 280],[580, 400],[320, 100]], sizeMapping: "mappinginreedvidslot", timeout: site_config.refresh_rate, },
inreedvid4Slot: { adUnitPath: "/slotnumber/slotname", size: [[550, 310],[728, 90],[300, 250],[250, 250],[468, 60],[320, 50],[336, 280],[580, 400],[320, 100]], sizeMapping: "mappinginreedvidslot", timeout: site_config.refresh_rate, },
inreedvid7Slot: { adUnitPath: "/slotnumber/slotname", size: [[550, 310],[728, 90],[300, 250],[250, 250],[468, 60],[320, 50],[336, 280],[580, 400],[320, 100]], sizeMapping: "mappinginreedvidslot", timeout: site_config.refresh_rate, },
inreedvid10Slot: { adUnitPath: "/slotnumber/slotname", size: [[550, 310],[970, 250],[970, 90],[728, 90],[300, 250],[250, 250],[468, 60],[320, 50],[336, 280],[580, 400],[320, 100]], sizeMapping: "mappinginreedvidslot", timeout: site_config.refresh_rate, },
inreedvid6Slot: { adUnitPath: "/slotnumber/slotname", size: [[970, 90],[728, 90],[468, 60],[320, 50],[320, 100]], sizeMapping: "mappingfooterslot", timeout: site_config.refresh_rate, },
},
```

can i add a querySelector to this, as when the divs get made on page depending which elements are there, there is a 
    div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">
, so i could use that to determine which of the "slots" to fire?

Comment: You have to check whether `.querySelector()` returns `null` before trying to add the new content.

Comment: slotsonpage.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null
    at slotsonpage.js:4

Comment: Yes, that's why you have to check for `null` **before** trying to add the new content.

Comment: ok, im a complete noobie to this, so dont know how to do that, edited quaetiosn with full code using

Comment: got all of this sorted out now, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the querySelector call returns something before trying to access.

To do this you need to add a condition.

You can also make use of an array to help make this process more graceful code-wise.

For example:

```js
//shows the slots on the page
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const ads = [
    {
      "selector": ".p-body-inner",
      "location": "afterbegin",
      "html": '<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423"><div id="advertisement" style="border: 0pt none; margin: auto; text-align: center; color: #999; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .2em; line-height: 1; margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top: -4px;">Advertisement</div><div id="inreedvid13Slot"></div></div><br>',
    },
    // This selector doesn't exist in this snippet and will be skipped by the condition below without crashing...
    {
      "selector": "#spacer1",
      "location": "afterbegin",
      "html": '<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423"><div id="advertisement" style="border: 0pt none; margin: auto; text-align: center; color: #999; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .2em; line-height: 1; margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top: -4px;">Advertisement</div><div id="inreedvid9Slot"></div></div><br><br><br>',
    },
    // Add your other ads here using similar structure above...
  ];
  ads.forEach(ad => {
    adContainer = document.querySelector(ad.selector);
    if (adContainer) {
      adContainer.insertAdjacentHTML(ad.location, ad.html);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="p-body-inner"></div>
```

Comment: thank you will try this out, some are beforebegin, some are afterbegin etc.  i see afterbegin in your code, how about the others though?

Comment: ah yes I missed those, you could add another property to the objects. updated my answer with the `location` property for each ad.

Comment: seems to work perfect,  on the pages where that element doesn't exist, its seems to still call the advert div but throw an error,  this is actually going to "ask/ call" for an ad but it never show, this might not be good for the advert suppliers and might get penalised, it calls for prebid bid and actually wins but as not there, cant display.  Can it NOT show the html if element not on page?  Warnings:
Warningspecktra_footer_1:googletag.defineSlot was called more times than there are DIVs in the DOM associated with ad slots while in Single Request Mode. This will impact impression counts.

Comment: actually that problem is caused by me prebid file i think, as that is trying to send all 8 adunitpaths to the page,  i think i need some logic around not sending those if the element was not found?             })(window.googletag, window.pbjs, {
definitons: {
inreedvid13Slot: { adUnitPath: "/ADUNITPATH/ADUNIT", size: [[970, 90],[970, 250],[728, 90],[468, 60],[320, 50],[320, 100]], sizeMapping: "mappingleaderslot", timeout: site_config.refresh_rate, },